# What does last-child do exactly?

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-class

Assuming I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="motiv_input_container">
     <div class="hide_if_necessary">
          <span class="motiv_label">&nbsp;</span>
          <span class="motive_head_text">Menge inkl. Ersatz</span><span class="motive_head_text">Gesamtpreis zzgl. MwSt</span>
     </div>
     <div class="motiv_input_holder"></div>
     <div class="motiv_input_holder"></div>
     <div class="motiv_input_holder"></div>
     <div class="motiv_input_holder"></div>
     <div class="motiv_input_holder"></div>
     <div class="motiv_input_holder"></div> <--- I WANT TO SELECT THIS ONE
     <div class="hide_if_necessary">
         <span class="motiv_label">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="motive_head_text">Gesamttotal zzgl. MwSt</span>
         <input type="text" class="motive_input_total_display">
      </div>
</div>
```

The `.motiv_input_holder` are added via JS with the following line:

```
$(this).parent().parent().children(".motiv_input_container")
.children(".hide_if_necessary:first-child")
.after("<div class='motiv_input_holder'></div>");
```

So, basically, they are added "between" the first and the second `".hide_if_necessary"`. Now, i want to be able to delete the last `".motiv_input_holder"`, however, I came across a small problem. My first attempt was this one:

```
$(this).parent().parent().children(".motiv_input_container").children(".motiv_input_holder:last-child").remove();
```

However, none of these were working even though they should have according to my logic (`last-of-child` didn't work either btw). Now, I solved it with the following:

```
$(this).parent().parent().children(".motiv_input_container").children(".motiv_input_holder:nth-last-child(2)").remove();
```

My question now is why? Shouldn't `last-child` do exactly what I'd like to in that case? Am i missing something?

Comment: What is the context of `this` in your JS?

Comment: `last-child` has to be the last child of it's parent.[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child). `.children(".motiv_input_holder:last")` should work.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery (and in CSS), [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) matches any element that is the last child of its parent. In your case, it is not: there is one more child after it. Classes are irrelevant in this context.